# Ruby on Rails Form_for error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I'm making a game in Ruby on Rails as a school project but now i'm stuck with this error:

undefined method `storylines_index_path' for #<#:0x007ff34cca8f68>

I'm making an page in which you I wou like to have a form to add an storyline, so I need a form with some fiels in it. I'd like to use the form_for method. But when adding I get this error

Here is my code:

views/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Overzicht Storylines') %> 
<h1>Voeg nieuwe storyline toe</h1>
<%= form_for(@storyline) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title%>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

storylines_controller.rb

```
class StorylinesController < ApplicationController   def index
  @storylines = Storylines.find(:all)   end

  def show
    @storyline = Storylines.find(params[:id])   
  end

  def new
    @storyline = Storylines.new   end end
```

storylines.rb

```
class Storylines < ActiveRecord::Base   
  attr_accessible :title, :text
end
```

routes.rb

```
StoryLine::Application.routes.draw do   
  get "users/new"   
  get "storylines/new"

  resources :users
  resources :storylines
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  match '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'

end
```

Comment: Generally it is related to routes and/or the object passed to `form_for`. Would you please post your `routes.rb` and the line of `form_for` in `new.html.erb`?

Comment: I have added the routes.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails conventions require that you name your model in a singular form, i.e., `Storyline` not `Storylines`. Renaming your model name in the class definition and the controllers should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
form_for(@storyline)
```

It will try to look for the **storylines_index_path**, in order to create a Storyline object into your database.

So you need to define the route on the file **config/routes.rb**, if you already defined **resources :storylines** that should define the route, if you don't want to create a REST resource, you can create your own route

```
match 'storylines/create', to: 'storylines#create', as: :storylines_create
```

and then on the view

I advise to read the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) since it explains much better everything related routing on rails

Comment: ok, I agree with Ahmad Sherif, rename storylines.rb to storyline.rb and rename the class Storylines to Storyline. Or just create a route that is named storylines_index_path to point to Storylines#index (very bad practice but it will work)

Comment: Nice, I will appreciate a positive vote for the effort, it builds my reputation and helps me to get better contracts ;)